# Model Not Performing Well On Validation Data - Customer Attrition Modeling

Tags: r, machine-learning, interpretation, overfitting, boosting

I am modeling customer churn for the online subscription. I looked back 90 days into customers’ data, using number customer watching behavior etc. I get a pretty strong model based on test data.

```
set.seed(42)
split <- 0.8
train_index <- createDataPartition(attrition_data_tbl$Attrition, p = split, list = FALSE)
train_attr <- attrition_data_tbl[train_index, ]
test_attr <- attrition_data_tbl[-train_index, ]
```

#### Summarize the target variables

```
table(train_attr$Attrition) / nrow(train_attr)
        No        Yes 
0.95804365 0.04195635
```

#### Building XGBOOST Model

```
## Create train/test indexes
## preserve class indices
set.seed(42)
my_folds <- createFolds(train_attr$Attrition, k = 5)

# Compare class distribution
i <- my_folds$Fold1
table(train_attr$Attrition[i]) / length(i)


## Reusing trainControl
my_control <- trainControl(
    summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
    classProbs = TRUE,
    verboseIter = TRUE,
    savePredictions = TRUE,
    index = my_folds
)

## Fit the Baseline Model 
model_xgb <- train(Attrition  ~ .,
                   data = train_attr,
                   method = "xgbTree",
                   metric = "ROC",
                   trControl = my_control
                   )
```

#### Predicting Test Data - xgboost

```
> confusionMatrix(predict(model_xgb, test_attr[, -1]), test_attr$Attrition, positive = 'Yes')
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction    No   Yes
       No  40582   516
       Yes     0  1261

               Accuracy : 0.9878          
                 95% CI : (0.9867, 0.9888)
    No Information Rate : 0.958           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       

                  Kappa : 0.824           
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : < 2.2e-16       

            Sensitivity : 0.70962         
            Specificity : 1.00000         
         Pos Pred Value : 1.00000         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.98744         
             Prevalence : 0.04195         
         Detection Rate : 0.02977         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.02977         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.85481         

       'Positive' Class : Yes
```

However, when I tried to validate my results by labeling each user as having attrited or not attrited in the next 30 days. I did not get what I was expecting. I am getting all user wrongly labbled. I do understand case of imblance classes. I tried different sampling methods e.g. under/over/mix sampling but still no luck.

#### Validation data

```
## Validation data = 1 month
valid_attr  <- attr_apr_tbl  %>%
    drop_na()

## Summarize the target variables for validation data 
table(valid_attr$Attrition) / nrow(valid_attr)

        No        Yes 
0.98638361 0.01361639 

> confusionMatrix(predict(model_xgb, valid_attr[, -1]), valid_attr$Attrition, positive = 'Yes')
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction     No    Yes
       No  213266   2944
       Yes      0      0

               Accuracy : 0.9864          
                 95% CI : (0.9859, 0.9869)
    No Information Rate : 0.9864          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.5049          

                  Kappa : 0               
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : <2e-16          

            Sensitivity : 0.00000         
            Specificity : 1.00000         
         Pos Pred Value :     NaN         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.98638         
             Prevalence : 0.01362         
         Detection Rate : 0.00000         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.00000         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.50000         

       'Positive' Class : Yes
```

Can anyone give me some insights so I can solve this problem. Or I should do different approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This might occur in the case that the underlying distribution is substantially different. It would make sense to check what are the most important variable in the train model and then check if substantial difference between the distribution of these features exist. A totally mechanistic problem that might happen is that the encoding of certain variables are is different but equivalent. How did this validation set came to be?

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks for the response. well, validation is nothing more than 30 days data for following month e.g. say I have data for training from Jan - March ( 3 months). I used April data for validation to see how my data performs.